# How do I get the menu items based on name or ID?

Tags: menus

I have this code that gets menu items, currently it works using slug-id (main-menu)

```
$menu_name = 'main-menu'; 

if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name])) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
}

foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
    $id = $menu_item->ID;
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    $url = $menu_item->url;
 
}
```

Is there a possibility to get menu items using their digit ID (ex: 45) or name   (ex: menu name)

Comment: [`wp_get_nav_menu_object`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_object/) accepts ID, name or slug.